# How can I check if nothing has been changed when posting back a form to MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an edit form in MVC and in my edit POST action I do a check before saving to ensure that I am not creating a duplicate. So for example if I change the title on my form then I check to see that title does not already exist.

However if I open the edit form and then submit without changing anything then the action checks to see if the title exists and flags it as a duplicate!

Is there some way that I can check if the Model is unchanged and if so then skip all the duplicate checks and attempts to save?

Right now the only check I have is:

```
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
```

Is there some equivalent for ModelState not changed?

Comment: You shouldn't do a POST to the same action when the user "closes  the form". When the user cancels the edit you should simply redirect him to somewhere else. Isn't that possible?

Comment: I am not doing that. When the user clicks "save" I return to the edit action that has [HttpPost]. My problem is that I have an error if the user has not changed anything because it sees the record as being a duplicate of the original.

Comment: So If the user changes something you want to save a new record. If he doesn't do any changes, then you simply ignore his action. Have I understand it correctly?

Comment: The question is how do I know he's not done any changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing the logic in the action rather than trying to see if the model has changed.

I assume that the record your are editing has an Id so the check you are currently doing fr duplicates is possibly something like:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM Table WHERE Title = @title
```

What if you changed that to

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM Table WHERE Title = @title AND Id <> @id
```

Wouldn't that solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues. The first is how to detect changes to a form's contents. This is subtler than handling change events and setting a flag. My current method is to serialize the form's selected values on page load using jQuery:

```
{     
    $('#ObjectState').text(this.getSerialized());
},

getSerialized: function () {
    return $('form *').filter(':input').not('[type="hidden"]').serialize();
}
```

Then during form submit:

```
if ($('#ObjectState').text() === this.getSerialized()) {
    alert('Nothing has changed on the form.');
    return false;
}
```

This stops them submitting if they haven't changed anything.

('ObjectState' is the name of a hidden variable whose initial value must always be empty. If you have more than one form on the page, change the jQuery selector from 'form *' to specify the exact form.)

Problem two has the correct solution by @lalibi above. You should check whether another entity (different id) is already using that Title. You should also have a unique index in the database for the Title field in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This one is to  check in  edit the  controller is modified or not in mvc  edit controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AuthorizeModelAccessActionFilter(TableID = TableID.Service_Country, Permission = Permission.Update)]
    public ActionResult Edit(Service_Country obj)
    {
        if (_context.Service_CountryQuery.Any(s => s.CurrencyID == obj.CurrencyID && s.MinPrice == obj.MinPrice) == true)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.UpdateService_Country(obj);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (_context.Service_CountryQuery.Any(s => s.CurrencyID == obj.CurrencyID && s.MinPrice == obj.MinPrice )==false)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {


                    _context.UpdateService_Country(obj);

                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Catalogue has been succesfully modified");
                    TempData["createinstanceerror"] = ModelState;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        return View(obj);
    }
```